# How to calculate Accuracy, Precision, and Recall for Multiple Bounding Boxes Without Objectness Score in a Single-Class Model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to analyze the performance of my object detection model. The model itself if trained on a single class, thus it produces outputs that it "thinks" are that specified class (i.e the letter 'a') in input images. Now, I have outputs of predicted bounding boxes as well as the ground truth boxes, but I am not sure how to produce tangible metrics.

The multiple predicted outputs for some image look like this, where each row is a separate prediction.

```
['449, 297, 449, 269, 502, 269, 502, 297',
 '226, 360, 193, 360, 193, 335, 226, 335',
 '248, 363, 248, 338, 285, 338, 285, 363']
```

The ground truth boxes are in the same format, where each row is a separate confirmed instance.

```
['420,296,479,295,478,264,419,265']
```

My thinking would be that I would have a double loop through the predicted boxes for a particular image, and then the ground truth boxes for that same image. Within that loop, I would calculate the IoU and if the calculated value is above some threshold, I would consider it a success. But, I am concerned this is the wrong approach, or I am reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have the same situation. I iterate over every ground truth bounding box and calculate the IOU for every detection. I assign the detection to the ground truth if the IOU is above 0.5. Then I want to calculate precision and recall rate by counting true and false positives etc. but I am still unsure how to do it in detail.

Comment: @Sandrogo I ended up gutting a lot of the code from this repo [link](https://github.com/Cartucho/mAP). Let me know if you got it or need help.